# supply power factor of a residential transformer

Tags: power, transformer, power-factor-correction

A transformer winding is generally more inductive than resistive thus there is a considerable phase difference between voltage and current, so wouldn't  the supply power factor be very very poor in case of residential transformers where no means for power factor corrections are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unloaded transformers look like inductors.  However, a resistive load on the secondary makes the primary look more resistive too.  For any decent transformer, the primary looks mostly resistive when the secondary is loaded with a resistance near the power limit of the transformer.

So the power factor is very poor when a transformer is drawing little power, and gets better as the power increases.  Fortunately, you care more about the power factor at high power levels.

All that said, the grid does generally look partially inductive.  Large industrial motors generally present a more inductive power factor than that added by typical transformers.

Large electric customers that pay extra for a low power factor usually have a system of compensating for the inductive power factor.  This is usually banks of capacitors that are switched across the power line to cancel out the inductance.

Comment: but how does a resistive load on the secondary side has anything to do with the inductance of primary , as there's no direct connection between the primary and secondary windings & the current drawn by primary in any case lags voltage by a considerable amount,as cosΦ =R/Z and R of primary is very very less than Reactance(inductive)

Comment: @SubratBavarianBastola, when there's a load on the secondary, energy from the generator is delivered to the load rather than being stored as magnetic flux in the core.

Comment: *"how does a resistive load on the secondary side has anything to do with the inductance of primary"* By the basic principle of what a transformer does.  Resistance is reflected across a transformer by the square of the turns ratio.  For example, a ideal transformer that drops 115 V to 12 V with a 3 Ohm load on the secondary will make the primary look like a 276 Ohm load.

Comment: okay, so you mean , if a resistive load is connected to the secondary of the transformer then the secondary current lags its secondary voltage by a considerably lesser phase angle Φ ?  For example,  resistive loads are connected across the secondary side of the transformer, here the secondary side of transformer acts as a localized energy  source for the loads , so the power supplied by transformer to loads  is V(secondary)*I(secondary) cos Φ , so if the secondary winding is considered more of an inductor than a resistor, won't the active power supplied to the resistive loads be insufficient ?

Comment: @Sub: It might help to think of the load presented by the primary as having two parts.  One is the inductor it is, and the other is the impedance of the secondary reflected by the square of the turns ratio.  At no load, you only have the inductive part.  At significant load, the reflected impedance dominates.  Due to how the transformer works, the inductive component actually goes down on its own (energy is transferred to the secondary, not stored in the core), in addition to becoming a smaller fraction of the whole due to the reflected load.

Comment: "smart meters" measure and report both VA and watts, and reports both. Which one is used for billing is up to the power company. So, yeah, after smart meters, an empty 10VA transformer _could_ be billed at 10 VA instead of ~0.5W! Public outrage is minimal thus far...

Comment: @dan: Electric power in most places, and certainly here in the US, is billed by actual energy used.  To put it in your terms, you pay for W, not VA.  However, large customers get a surcharge, or their rate goes up, if their power factor is too low.  This incentivises them to maintain a good power factor, hence the banks of capacitors that get switched in as needed to offset inductance from motors and the like.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: yeah, commercial has long been monitored, but residential spinny-wheel meters didn't count apparent power, while new smart meters can. If you have lots of wall-worts, review your TOS; some idle vampire AC/DC adapters would move from pennies a month to dollars, _if_ the utility charges for such uses.\